# Codeigniter auto removes slashes in db queries?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a SQL INSERT query that has a field that has a slash in it. Here is the string in PHP:

`'\\\\192.168.2.10\\datastore'`

Here it is when I echo it out:

`'\\192.168.2.10\datastore'`

The above string is part of a query and is used in this method:

`$this->db->query($sql);`

However, when I view the database it has been written as:

`\192.168.2.10datastore`

How can I stop this from happening? What do I turn off to stop codeigniter from doing this?

### Update

```
var $clients_array = array(
    1 => array('datastore' => '\\\\192.168.2.10\\datastore'),
);

function(){

//loop here

$client_details = $this->clients_array[1];
$datastore = $client_details['datastore']; 

$sql = "INSERT INTO table (datastore) VALUES ('$datastore')";

//$sql = "INSERT INTO table (datastore) VALUES ('".$datastore."')"; //tried this too

echo $sql;

if($this->db->query($sql)){}

}
```

Comment: Can you show some code with test outputs? At which point prior to running the query does the transformation happen?

Comment: @Pekka the echo that you see in the question (second one) is right above the actual query. Updating question.

Comment: @Abs: Why does the echo not contain the full SQL query then?

Comment: @hakre I was trying to simplify code. The query is quite large.

Comment: Then put it in otherwise it's not clear what is happening.

Comment: @hakre I don't think adding the query is going to help. I did the same insert with just that one field and slashes are being removed.

Comment: Then I can only guess from your code: Looks like you remove them on your own. The sql is not exectued yet, it just contains what's in your array of data.

Comment: @hakre what do you mean it's not executed? It makes a call to the query function. It's something to do with the double quotes I think as PHP is parsing it and the backslash is an escape character, but no idea why though.

Comment: You echo the `$sql` *before* you do the query call.

Comment: I just did a `$this->db->last_query();` which shows me the last query performed and it shows it the way I want it to appear in the db `\\192.168.2.10\datastore` - however in the db it appears as `'\192.168.2.10datastore'` - wth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be overlooking something, but those backslashes are escape characters as you know, in both PHP and MySQL. You need to escape them for your query or they will escape themselves.

```
$datastore = $this->db->escape($client_details['datastore']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (datastore) VALUES ('$datastore')";
```

I'm pretty sure `mysql_real_escape_string()` would be fine as well, but we're using CI so might as well make the most of it.

Consider using CI's Active Record, which escapes all queries automatically, or query bindings (reference in linked page), otherwise you must do it manually as usual.

More on escaping queries with CI: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Comment: Perfect! Wrapping `mysql_real_escape_string` around the troublesome variable sorts it out. I just realised that a backslash is an escape character for mysql as well. I was just focusing on PHP! Thank you very much for the help. I just made use of `$this->db->escape` as I am using CI.

Comment: Better go through the rest of your queries and make sure you're escaping them properly. I highly recommend using CI's Active Record. This is like MySQL/PHP basics, escaping queries.

Comment: I was hoping to be nearer to the DB and do without a layer of abstraction but I'll look into it!